# Send POST request from python to laravel

Tags: python, laravel, post, request

I need to send a dictionary, with a POST request, created in Python to a web pages made in Laravel. I saw in Internet that I need to import a request library but I don't understood how does it works.

My python script is this:

```
 mac_dict = {}

def readFile():
    with open("/home/pi/Desktop/Progetti SIoTD/device.txt", "r") as file:
        for i in file:
            line, *lines = i.split()
            if line in mac_dict:
                mac_dict[line] += lines
            else:
                mac_dict[line] = lines
    print(mac_dict)
    print("\n")
    return mac_dict

'''
def get_all_values(nested_dictionary):
    for key, value in nested_dictionary.items():
        if type(value) is dict:
            get_all_values(value)
        else:
            print(key, ":", value)
    print("\n")
'''
def getValues(dict, mac):
    s = 0
    rssi_val = []
    for key in dict:
        if key == mac:
            k = dict.get(mac)
            for i in range(len(k)):
                if i % 2 == 0:
                    rssi = k[i]
                    rssi = int(rssi)
                    print(rssi)
                    rssi_val.append(rssi)
                else:
                    k_v = k[i]
                    print(k_v)

    for i in range(len(rssi_val)):
        s += rssi_val[i]

    average = s / len(rssi_val)
    return average

readFile()
#get_all_values(mac_dict)
getValues(mac_dict, 'C4:A5:DF:24:05:7E')
```

How can I made it?
Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

I need to send the dictionary that I read from a file (function readFile)...this file is a TXT file that contain MAC address, RSSI and a string with time; also the file is in a Raspberry Pi4 model B that I use for scan bluetooth signal and create the TXT file

Comment: `requests.post(url, data={..dictionary...})`

Comment: you have missleading names of variables - it should be rather `for line in file:`

Comment: it is not clear what data you want to send. You show how you read some data from file but better show example data which you want to POST to server.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't explain what data you want to send - so I can only show basic syntax.

```
import requests

url = 'https://...'

my_dict = {...}

response = requests.post(url, data=my_dict)

print(response.text)
```

But all may depends on details which you didn't show in question.

---

Minimal working code which use portal `httpbin.org` for test.
It sends back all headers from POST

```
import requests

url = 'https://httpbin.org/post'

my_dict = {'message': 'hello world'}

response = requests.post(url, data=my_dict)

print(response.text)
```

Result:

```
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {
    "message": "hello world"
  }, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br", 
    "Content-Length": "19", 
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "python-requests/2.26.0", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-6176a644-76c6320f5f4ae9b05a118b2f"
  }, 
  "json": null, 
  "origin": "79.163.228.53", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/post"
}
```

It shows `"form": {"message": "hello world"}` which I send to server.

Answer (score 0):

If you have websites written in 2 different languages, the most robust method to establish a relationship between them is the API method. You can accept post request by typing api in the system written in Laravel. Then you can easily send the text or file by python in this post request to laravel api url.

Answer (score 0):

send API and In Laravel use

```
`public function __construct(){
 $data = "//API Here//";
 $this->data = $data;
}`

`public function store(){
      // rest of the code here you can find any where
 }
  `
```